# i want to select yesterday entred data for display

Tags: mysql

I want to select yesterday entered data I entered two codes but not work well. The code and table structure is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM reg_data3 
WHERE date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY  ;

SELECT * 
FROM reg_data3 
WHERE date = (str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) - INTERVAL 1 DAY  ;

CREATE TABLE `reg_data3` (
  `date` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `rainfall` float default NULL,
  `evep` float default NULL,
  `max_temp` float default NULL,
  `min_temp` float default NULL,
  `sunshine_hrs` float default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What doesn´t work as expected?

Comment: Try `subdate(current_date, 1)` to have yesterday date.

Comment: @idonteven no results but field are display

Answer (score 0):

in mysql you can try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM reg_data3 
WHERE date = DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Read about
[date_sub](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)